# How do I modify Rc<RefCell> from inside the closure?

Tags: rust

I am trying to pass RefCell to a function in a closure and then modify the same variable from inside the closure. Here is my code:

```
let path: Rc<RefCell<Option<Vec<PathBuf>>>> = Rc::new(RefCell::new(None));

...
//valid value assigned to path
...

let cloned_path = path.clone();

button_run.connect_clicked(move |_| {
    let to_remove: usize = open_dir(&mut cloned_path.borrow_mut().deref_mut());
    //Here I need to remove "to_remove" index from cloned_path
});

//Choose a random directory from Vec and open it. Returns opened index.
fn open_dir(path_two: &mut Option<Vec<PathBuf>>) -> usize {
    let vec = path_two.clone();
    let vec_length = vec.unwrap().len();

    let mut rng = thread_rng();
    let rand_number = rng.gen_range(0, vec_length);

    let p: &str = &*path_two.clone().expect("8")[rand_number].to_str().unwrap().to_string();

    Command::new("explorer.exe").arg(p).output();

    rand_number.clone()
}
```

First I thought that since my `open_dir()` function accepts `&mut`, I can modify the vector inside the function. But no matter what I tried I kept getting `cannot move out of borrowed content` error.
Then I thought - ok, I can return the index from the function and access `cloned_path` from the closure itself. But the only code that I could get to compile is

```
button_run.connect_clicked(move |_| {
    let to_remove: usize = open_dir(&mut cloned_path.borrow_mut().deref_mut());
    let x = &*cloned_path.borrow_mut().clone().unwrap().remove(to_remove);
});
```

It works, but it removes from a cloned version of `cloned_path`, leaving the original unaffected. Is there a way to access `cloned_path` directly to modify it's contents and if there is one, how do I approach this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main way to modify contents of an enum value (and `Option` is enum) is pattern matching:

```
fn do_something(path_two: &mut Option<Vec<PathBuf>>) {
    if let Some(ref mut paths) = *path_two {
        paths.push(Path::new("abcde").to_path_buf());
    }
}
```

Note that `paths` pattern variable is bound with `ref mut` qualifier - it means that it will be of type `&mut Vec<PathBuf>`, that is, a mutable reference to the internals of the option, exactly what you need to modify the vector, in case it is present.